# Is there any way to save cart data when a user logs out?

Tags: codeigniter, shopping-cart

I'm using cart session in Codeigniter. My problem is when the buyers log out, the cart sessions are destroyed. How can I keep the cart data which were not processed yet for customers who come back and login in again?

Comment: I have deleted my answer because it's not the correct answer sorry about that i think [ShadowElf](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7821496/shadowelf) was right.

Comment: from CI docs: The Cart library is DEPRECATED and should not be used. It is currently only kept for backwards compatibility. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html#shopping-cart-class

Answer (score 1):

You must add a procedure when logout to save data in database.

And, when login... take from database and add to cart.

Is the only solution, or you must rewrite entire cart code.

My solution: database cart, and a cookie :) so no matter if you're logged in or not. And you can see what is in cart(s) as admin.

When you do logout... you must add something like this:

```
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items){
$this->db->from('temp_cart');
$this->db->set('id_user', LOGGED USER ID);
$this->db->set('cart_row', json_encode($items));
$this->db->insert();
}
```

when you log-in

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('temp_cart');
$this->db->where('id_user', LOGGED USER ID);
$res=$this->db->get();
foreach($res->result_array() as $row{
   $row=json_decode($row, TRUE);
   $this->cart->insert($row);
}

$this->db->from('temp_cart');
$this->db->where('id_user', LOGGED USER ID);
$this->db->delete();
```

Comment: hmm dont really understand, can you give me some reference links or tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

When you do logout... you must add something like this:

```
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items)
{
    $this->db->from('temp_cart');
    $this->db->set('id_user', $this->session->userdata('customer_id'));
    $this->db->set('cart_row', json_encode($items));
    $this->db->insert();
}
```

when you log-in:

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('temp_cart');
    $this->db->where('id_user', $this->session->userdata('customer_id'));
    $res=$this->db->get();
if($res)
{
    foreach($res->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $row=json_decode($row['cart_row'], TRUE);
        $productData = array(
        'id'      => $row['id'],
        'qty'     => $row['qty'],
        'price'   => $row['price'],
        'name'    => $row['name'],
        'options' => array('img_path' => $row['options']['img_path'])
        );
        $rowId = $this->cart->insert($productData); 
    }

    $this->db->from('temp_cart');
    $this->db->where('id_user', $this->session->userdata('customer_id'));
    $this->db->delete();
}
```